# Changing if else from static to dynamic in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have an if else condition where, if I upload a file, it will see for the 'code name' i.e, 'abc1' in the file name and compare it to a hard coded value and the returned value will then be compared to a ProductLine. Here I am doing a two way search. how to get rid of all these if elses and make it straight like if I upload a file compare it with productLine and then return it. Below is the code.

```
    var findProductLineByFilename = function(filename, productLines) {
    filename = filename.replace(/( |\-|\.|_)/g, '');
    var i;
    for (i in productLines) {
        productLine = productLines[i];

        // XXX: Hard-code names
        if (productLine.code_name === 'abc1') {
            if (filename.search(/(war1)|(w1)|(abc1)/) >= 0) {
                return productLine;
            }
        } else if (productLine.code_name == 'abc2') {
            if (filename.search(/(w2)|(abc2)/) >= 0) {
                return productLine;
            }
        } else if (productLine.code_name == 'abc3') {
            if (filename.search(/(w3)|(abc3)/) >= 0) {
                return productLine;
            }
        } else if (productLine.code_name == 'abc4') {
            if (filename.search(/(w4)|(abc4)/) >= 0) {
                return productLine;
            }
        } else if (productLine.code_name == 'abc5') {
            if (filename.search(/(w5)|(abc5)/) >= 0) {
                return productLine;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: Where do the alternatives come from? We can see that `abcN` comes from the code name, but what about the `wN` part?

Answer (score 1):

Use an object to map code names to regular expressions.

```
var findProductLineByFilename = function(filename, productLines) {
    filename = filename.replace(/( |\-|\.|_)/g, '');
    var map = {
        'abc1': /(war1)|(w1)|(abc1)/,
        'abc2': //(w2)|(abc2)/,
        ...
    };
    var i;
    for (var i = 0; i < productLines.length; i++) {
        productLine = productLines[i];
        if (productLine.code_name in map && map[productLine.code_name].test(filename)) {
            return productLine;
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: What I am trying here is to get rid of hard coding. I mean using object to map is still hard coding. productLine should directly come from the product list

Comment: I don't see how to do that. How is it supposed to know that `code_name == 'acb1'` is related to `war1`, `w1`, and `acb1` in the filename, but `code_name = 'acb2'` is related only to `w2` and `acb2`. There doesn't seem to be a common pattern to all the tests.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "come directly from the product list". What is the product list?